# TFS Migration from 2005 to 2008?

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

Does anybody know if it is possible to migrate separate projects from a TFS 2005 server to a TFS 2008 Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded a TFS server from 2005 to 2008, but never migrated projects from one to the other.  I can tell you that I have projects that use VS2005 in my VS2008 server and it works with no problems.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for since i was hoping to get rid of some of the clutter and start with a fresh install. But I am afraid tat I can't find any other way to do it either.

Answer (score 1):

A "crude but effective" way could be to do the full upgrade and then [Delete the Team Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181482.aspx) you don't want on the new server.

That said - you should be able to accomplish much of what you want (with some limitations) using the [TFS to TFS Migration utility](http://www.codeplex.com/tfstotfsmigration) on CodePlex.  You may want to read through the discussions - some people had some issues with branches - you'll need to make sure you have your mappings correct.